# Recreating this synth sound

Tags: synthesizer, replication, how-to

I would like to know some advice on start recreating the kind of sound you find at about 0:13 of this video:

Ie the "growling bass". I tried with some BP fileterd triangle wave, but it does not have the same thickness and movement.

Comment: Felice, what synths do you have at your disposal? For example, this could probably be created in several different ones, but the steps will be different.

Comment: @JYelton no real synths, just DAW. If you have an example, I can get the idea and choose the proper software

Comment: Well that's what I mean. The sound could be done in a number of vst synths. NI Massive, U-he Zebra2, Sylenth, etc. Which ones you use will help get you more specific info.

Comment: @JYelton what about ES2? or EFM1? But if you know how to do with Sylenth, I can reproduce

Comment: currently at work so can't listen to the sound, but I'll do my best to re-create it when I get back home today